# Convert List Object[] to MultiMap

Tags: java, collections, multimap

I have a query which returns `List of Object[2]`. I would like to convert this into a `MultiMap` which would contain `Object[0]` as key and `Object[1]` as value.

input list contains:

```
<id1, value1>
<id1, value2>
<id1, value3>
<id2, value1>
<id2, value2>
<id3, value2>
```

So when I do `Collection coll = (Collection) multimap.get(id1);`

`col1` Should give --> `value1,value2,value3`

I can achive this looping through the list and putting it to the multimap, I would like to avoid that as my List is huge.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which Multimap are you using?  Apache?  Guava?

Comment: Would you like to use third-party MultiMap implementation or to create one yourself?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Apache.

Comment: @Darkhogg: I was able to do it looping through the list, But I would like to avoid that and get the same result.

Comment: not really anyway around looping that i can see.  At most you'll find some library that loops for you.

Comment: "I would like to avoid that as my List is huge." This doesn't make sense - you can't punt all items from collection A to collection B without iterating over collection A.

Comment: You will have to loop through it. Also, measure before making assumptions. 'Huge' is quite relative and the time spent in putting the values in the multimap might be a few nano seconds only...

Comment: Addendum: if you use the MultiHashMap remember to preinitialize the multimap with the number of expected values in order to avoid unnecessary rehashing.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses, I was hoping some library which does this for me.  Your inputs are appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(Object obj[] : list ){
    multimap.put(obj[0], obj[1]);
}
```

Assuming youre using apache multimap

Comment: I would like to use something where I don't have to loop through.

Comment: @Gayathri No such thing exists.

Comment: A matter of style, but I find clearer for begginers `Object[] obj` rather than `Object obj[]`

Comment: @Darkhogg Clearer for anyone really. The latter is a C artefact, the former notation makes more sense given Java's type model.

Comment: Sorry, im more used to C Conventions and it shows in my java code